# CSS gradients look incorrect after jQuery changes content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small web-app I'm developing for myself.

When I click the add button, it calls some .load functions to return the error message and the updated table.

However, it causes the gradients to look like this (look around the error message and to the top left/right of the table):

[image]

The gradient is set to the background of the containing div (The grey one inside the green one). The jQuery loads in a single `<p>` for the message and a `<table>` for the table.

I can't see why this would happen to the gradient, as it works fine on the initial page load (before jQuery updates it).

Is there anyway to force the background to 'refresh'? It fixes itself if you inspect element or change to a different tab then back to this one.

Comment: What browser are you using? Also, do you have any example code with the error so that we can reproduce and test it? Possible on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: This is on Chrome. I'm not bothering with IE at the moment as I'm using a lot of HTML5 and it just doesn't work in IE9. I can try putting it on jsfiddle but the jQuery calls are to php scripts on my local server.

Comment: It doesn't have to be your exact code, a scaled down version of the minimum code required to cause the problem will do and is actually preferred. It might even help you solve the problem when creating said case.

Comment: you should share a little of the CSS and jQuery code if you want to get a real answer

Answer (score 2):

With the limited information provided, I would assume it is less an issue with the "background gradient" and more an issue of the elements in the foreground having an opaque and/or colored background being overlaid on top of the background gradient.

Have you styled the `<p>` in question to have a transparent background, or is there a background color being applied to it (either directly or inherently)?

Please provide more info (the CSS and a bit of HTML) for the problem for a better answer.

Comment: The CSS is fine everywhere else though, it's only when the content changes with jQuery (which does nothing to the styling, just returns text). I can even break the gradient by highlighting anywhere on the page with just my cursor... If the CSS was broken, why does inspect element fix it? Oh and the shape of the areas that are incorrect don't match the HTML layout at all, it just bleeds/spreads by itself. Once you inspect element to fix it, it works correctly until you refresh.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am experiencing the same and would love to know if you fixed the issue.